# when i use spring-cloud openfeign， oepnfeign error => com.netflix.client.ClientException

Tags: java, spring-cloud, stack-overflow, feign, openfeign

The test environment service is normal, and there is no such problem. However, such a situation often occurs in the production environment. After GC analysis, it is found that there is no memory problem. This situation still occurs after adjusting the JVM XSS parameters. Does anyone encounter this situation? The following is a complete trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.netflix.client.ClientException
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:90)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.seata.feign.SeataLoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(SeataLoadBalancerFeignClient.java:45)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TraceLoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(TraceLoadBalancerFeignClient.java:75)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TraceFeignAspect.executeTraceFeignClient(TraceFeignAspect.java:66)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TraceFeignAspect.feignClientWasCalled(TraceFeignAspect.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor287.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.seata.feign.SeataLoadBalancerFeignClient$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$21ea282.execute(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TraceLoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(TraceLoadBalancerFeignClient.java:75)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:119)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)
    at feign.hystrix.HystrixInvocationHandler$1.run(HystrixInvocationHandler.java:109)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:100)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:56)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:47)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.seata.feign.hystrix.SeataHystrixConcurrencyStrategy$SeataContextCallable.call(SeataHystrixConcurrencyStrategy.java:163)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.TraceCallable.call(TraceCallable.java:71)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:69)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: null
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:118)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:83)
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.retry.RetryException: Could not recover; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancedRecoveryCallback.recover(LoadBalancedRecoveryCallback.java:56)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.handleRetryExhausted(RetryTemplate.java:512)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:351)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.RetryableFeignLoadBalancer.execute(RetryableFeignLoadBalancer.java:92)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.RetryableFeignLoadBalancer.execute(RetryableFeignLoadBalancer.java:52)
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient$1.call(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:104)
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:303)
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:287)
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:231)
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:228)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.drain(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:286)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:144)
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:185)
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:127)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:79)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45)
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209)
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138)
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390)
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:443)
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340)
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:112)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.BHttpConnectionBase.fillInputBuffer(BHttpConnectionBase.java:342)
    at org.apache.http.impl.BHttpConnectionBase.isStale(BHttpConnectionBase.java:362)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPool.validate(CPool.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPool.validate(CPool.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2.get(AbstractConnPool.java:256)
    at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2.get(AbstractConnPool.java:198)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:306)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$1.get(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:282)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:190)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at feign.httpclient.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:83)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.seata.feign.SeataFeignClient.execute(SeataFeignClient.java:59)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyTracingFeignClient.execute(LazyTracingFeignClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TracingFeignClient.execute(TracingFeignClient.java:81)
```

Comment: Could you please upgrade your dependencies (use latest) and try again?

Comment: it doesnot works. - -

Comment: Could you please create a **minimal** sample project on github that reproduces the issue and open a new issue in Sleuth's repo?

Comment: Could you have any ideas about this, just make me to reappearance this problem.   I cant reappearance it in my develop environment， it just happened in kubernetes environment. I'm going crazy about this problem.

Comment: here is my emai mersycle@hotmail.com, it will be nice if i can receive any message from u